# Problem with adding bookmark in Files

Tags: pantheon-files

Given how immediately familiar Files felt when coming from Finder, I was surprised to see a drag-drop of a folder to the sidebar not resulting in the creation of a bookmark.

Did I miss something obvious here or are bookmarks simply not supported?

Comment: Can you please tell which version of elementary OS are you using? I just did create a bookmark on my elementary OS Juno.

Comment: And if you can't bookmark a folder by drag-and-drop, please go to the folder you want to bookmark and press Ctrl+D. Please let know what you find.

Comment: Thank you for your follow-up. I am on Juno as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press right button on any folder you want to bookmark and click on *Bookmark*, you will see your desired folder in the sidebar in [files](/questions/tagged/files).

And as Hasan suggested,

> Please go to the folder you want to bookmark and press
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

this should work too.

Comment: Thanks - this did indeed work and suddenly I was also able to drag-drop to create sidebar bookmarks and rearrange them. Unfortunately this ability quickly went away again. I have not been able to establish very great stability on this install.

Comment: That is something wrong with mouse/touchpad i guess. But that is another issue. If you face problem with mouse / touchpad create another question unless a question already covers your issue and it has answers.

Comment: When dragging onto the sidebar make sure you drop between existing bookmarks (drag icon has "copy" emblem - white cross on green) not onto a bookmark (drag icon has "move" emblem - black cross on white - if local bookmark but "copy" emblem if on a different filesystem).  The context menu or shortcut key is probably safer.